# Inserting float in DynamoDB with PHP

Tags: php, floating-point, amazon-dynamodb

I'm in the process of a shift from MongoDB to DynamoDB and one of the challenges I still haven't found a solution to, is inserting floats.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime()); 
$timestamp = (float)$usec + (float)$sec; //1379914632.0291
$array_to_insert = array('system_insert_time' => array('N' => $timestamp));
```

I'm getting an exception like this:

```
Validation errors: [Item][system_insert_time][N] must be of type string
```

The field in the database is defined as a Number. It's working fine if I'm trying to insert integers. But I need more accuracy than seconds. Inserting as a string doesn't work, because I want  to be able to get database entries greater than a specific timestamp.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it works if I use number_format() on the timestamp before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

You already found a solution, so I just like to add that type-casting to string would be another...

```
$array_to_insert = array('system_insert_time' => array('N' => (string)$timestamp));
#                                                             ^------^
```